# AEM 5.6.1 | slowness while opening CRXDE or package manager

Tags: performance, aem

When I am trying to open CRXDE (`http://IP:4502/crx/de/index.jsp`) or package manager (`http://IP:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp`) it takes a lot of time to load the page. Sometime around ~12 minutes.

Nothing has changed recently, so not sure where should I start looking for issue. I analyzed the request logs and found that mentioned files are taking a lot of time to load. This issue is intermittent as sometimes console opens just fine. Any suggestions?

```
D:\CQ5.6\crx-quickstart\opt\helpers>java -jar rlog.jar -n 20 request1.log
*Error* Not matching request line found for [6443638]
*Info * Parsed 146845 requests.
*Info * Time for parsing: 445ms
*Info * Time for sorting: 74ms
*Info * Total Memory: 429mb
*Info * Free Memory: 363mb
*Info * Used Memory: 65mb
------------------------------------------------------
   1098203ms 03/Dec/2014:07:58:19 +0100 200 GET /crx/packmgr/endorsed/extjs/ext-all-debug.js application/javascript
    996178ms 03/Dec/2014:08:43:05 +0100 200 GET /crx/de/endorsed/extjs/ext-all-debug.js application/javascript
    843041ms 03/Dec/2014:08:26:51 +0100 200 GET /crx/packmgr/endorsed/extjs/ext-all-debug.js application/javascript
     93040ms 03/Dec/2014:11:36:14 +0100 200 GET /etc/clientlibs/pritt/pritt.all.scripts.js application/x-javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

those numbers are not normal for the files you mention (~1.5MB each). Often the quickest way to optimize things on a dev box is simply to dump the server and install another :-) otherwise you can learn the production way (with simple machine) and look at what are the concurrent threads leading to this.

Be aware that in the end, such performance issues are often file system related (rather than CPU), either another thread on the server, or another process on your machine is probably eating all the resources.